# how to modify database data after fetching it in react

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have a few js that only contain export const and those are not any class or function.
I have an async-await function to fetch data from the database. Now I need to create another const that will only fetch the first data from the result. and there is another const where I need to set that data.

data fetching const in db.js

```js
export const getLatestData = async () => {
  const url = `${testDB.serverUrl}/findLatestTen`;
  const res = await axios.get(url).then(res => res);
  return res;
};
```

I have another function that will retrieve only the first value

```js
export const getFirst = async () => {
  const test = await getLatestData();
  const example = test.data[0].salary;
  // If I put console.log here I get the example value as expected
};
```

But I have another js file called employee.js where I have some const like this

```js
export const details = [
  {
    title: 'HR',

    links: [
      {
        title: 'Employee 1',
        salary: async () => {
          await getFirst();
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Employee 2',
        salary: async () => {
          await getFirst();
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I will use this employee.js to set value in the UI. But I am not getting the value. Can I please get some help?

TIA

Comment: should be `salary: () => { getFirst(); }`, now it just a promise, you need to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

`await getFirst()` will just run the function. If you want to get the you should return the function.

```js
export const getFirst = async () => {
  const test = await getLatestData();
  const example = test.data[0].salary;
  return example; // return value
};
```

```js
export const details = [
  {
    title: 'HR',

    links: [
      {
        title: 'Employee 1',
        salary: async () => {
          return await getFirst();  // return function result
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Employee 2',
        salary: async () => {
          return await getFirst();  // return function result
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: I tried this but if I do this.  salary: async () => {
          return await getFirst();  // return function result
        }.   then  autofix  removes that return and I am still getting the error

Comment: If I do like this          salary: async () => {
          const ex = await getFirst();
          console.log(`ex ${ex}`);
          return ex;   }. Then I am getting  async () => {
      const ex = await Object(_pbfs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["getFirst"])();
      console.log(`ex ${ex}`);
      return ex;   I am calling this pbf from a class and there I put a log

Comment: you'd better not export `details` array. Just define the array on where you're using it.

Comment: I can't change it, unfortunately. Because that's an existing structure. Basically, my goal is getFirst() should return a string and I want to use getFirst() may places

Comment: what is the exact error when you try to use like `details[0].links[0].salary`?

Comment: I am getting const ex = await Object(_pbfs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["getFirst"])();      console.log(`ex ${ex}`);      return ex;  instead of actual value

Comment: so you can't customize using `details` on where it is used?

Comment: no.. the salary object expects a string. I need to send a string there